# I need to retrieve ALL images (regardless of number and name) from a local folder and display them on my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have seen a number of questions similar to this, but none that completely answered my question in a manner I understood.

I am building a website in which I would like to have a specified folder from which to retrieve all images (these could change from day to day, so I can't have it based on the file name, but rather the file path to that folder) and display them on the page. As of right now, I've seen a number of examples of doing something like this using PHP, Javascript, Ajax.... Lots.

However, I'm still having trouble implementing these examples or others' ideas into my own code. Below is a couple pieces of code that I've been trying to make work; I pulled these from various examples and ATTEMPTED to customize it for my needs, but have been unable to get a working HTML showing in my browser (Google Chrome).

Here's my PHP script:

```
<?
    //PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
     Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

    //This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
    //and outputs them as a JavaScript array
    function returnimages($dirname=".") {
        $pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image 
        extensions
        $files = array();
        $curimage=0;
        if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
            while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
                if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
                    //Output it as a JavaScript array element
                     echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
                    $curimage++;
                }
            }

            closedir($handle);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf($files(i))
        }
        return($files);
    }

    echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
    returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
    ?>
```

And here is my HTML file:

```
<script src="http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/phpslide.images.php"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var curimg=0
function rotateimages(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "phpslide/"+galleryarray[curimg])
    curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0
}
 
window.onload=function(){
    setInterval("rotateimages()", 2500)
}
</script>
 
<div style="width: 170px; height: 160px">
<img id="slideshow" src="pics/bear.gif"/>
</div>
```

Can someone either walk me through what I'm doing wrong in these pieces of code, or provide me an idea of how to do what I want here? If you do answer, explanations would be appreciated to :) Still in the learning process here!

Comment: Retrieving all the images from a folder is easy. But perhaps you should explain what exactly you're going to do with them? I mean, I can tell you to use [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get a list of all the files inside the directory and loop through the array to display them. But it seems to me you're working on an image slider?

Comment: That does sound very accurate to what I'm trying to do. Basically, on this website, the business owner will place images into a folder that the code pulls from. No matter what images are there, the code needs to see them. The images (all of them) will then be displayed on a page corresponding to that type of picture that was placed in the folder (we have separate folders for each page). So say you have IMG1, IMG2, and IMG3 in FolderX, and IMG4, IMG5, and IMG6 in FolderY. I need PageX to show IMG1, IMG2, and IMG3, and PageY to show 4-6.. If I replace IMG2 with IMG7, I need that to be reflected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is solid, there are just some details in the execution that need to be cleaned up. I took a swing at setting this up locally and cleaning it up a bit.

PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * This PHP script returns javascript that feeds an image gallery. A JSON array of images are returned along with a
 * parameter that indicated the base URL for the images.
 *
 */

/**
 * @var $localImageDir string
 * The path to the local image directory relative to this script
 */
$localImageDir = 'img';

/**
 * @var $baseUrl string
 * The URL path to the image directory
 */
$baseUrl = 'http://localhost/img/';

/**
 * This function returns an array of image file names in the specified directory. The output is limited
 * using the limit parameter
 *
 * @param string $localImageDir
 * @param string $baseUrl
 * @param int $limit
 * @return array
 */
function returnImages($localImageDir = '.', $baseUrl='', $limit = 5)
{
    //valid image extensions
    $pattern = "/(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)/";

    $files = array();
    if ($handle = opendir($localImageDir))
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            //Use preg_match here, eregi is deprecated
            if (preg_match($pattern, $file))
            {
                $files[] = $baseUrl.$file;
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }

    // Limit results
    $output = array_slice($files, 0, $limit);

    return $output;
}

// Get the image list as an array
$imageArray = returnImages($localImageDir, $baseUrl);

//Encode the image array as JSON
$json = json_encode($imageArray);

//Set the appropriate HTTP header and echo the JavaScript
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
echo 'var galleryImages=' . $json.';';
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="images.php"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var curImg=0;
        function rotateImages()
        {
            document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", galleryImages[curImg]);
            curImg=(curImg<galleryImages.length-1)? curImg+1 : 0;
        }

        window.onload=function()
        {
            setInterval("rotateImages()", 2500)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 170px; height: 160px">
    <img id="slideshow" src="pics/bear.gif"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In your original script, there were some syntax errors in your for loop - those "i"s need $s. Also, $files(i) should be $files[i]. Beyond that, you're doing a lot of work that you don't need to do, you can simply create an array of file names and use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to format them properly for JavaScript. It's also a good idea to have the base URL to your images set up as a variable in this script rather than in the client. We can send that along with the image data.

You're also using [eregi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php), which is deprecated, I replaced that with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), which requires a small tweak to your regex.

On the HTML side, I just added correct barebones markup, and changed function and variable names to be a bit more readable, and changed the script to use the variable base URL.

You will need to change the path to the PHP script in the HTML, I just changed it for my local setup.

Good luck.

Comment: Whoops! As you can see, I totally just copied the script from a website to try and make it work. Once I have the basics down, I can manipulate it a bit. Please excuse the dumb question, but what is the difference between your galleryPath and imagePath? I will have X number pictures in a folder, and I have to pull all those pictures to be displayed on the page. I'm refraining from hardcoding image names as images will be removed and replaced at various times.

Comment: $imagePath is the path to the directory that the returnImages function should look in. Gallery path is the URL that the client script prepends to the file name to create the full path to the image. So if your script is in /gallery/ and your images are in /gallery/images, $imagePath would be "images" and $galleryPath would be "/gallery/images/". Or if your client is not served from the same site, $gallery path would be "http://example.com/gallery/images/".

If you really want all of the images without a limit, just comment our the line with array_slice.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, then, everywhere that your code currently says $dirPath should actually be $galleryPath. Correct? Or is $dirPath a completely different variable that I've just managed to completely miss here?

Comment: No, $galleryPath only goes to the client, it is the base URL for the images. $imagePath is the path to the directory your images are in on the server relative to the PHP file. $dirPath is a local variable in the returnImages functino. If that is confusing you, you can change the name of the $imagePath variable to $dirPath to be consistent. The code that I posted runs just fine as long as you set the two variables correctly.

Comment: My understanding of these file path references seems to be flawed. I have both my PHP script and HTML file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot (I'm using IIS for a localhost server). I am getting a 404 not found error when running the HTML file in my browser. It can't seem to find the PHP script, which I have referenced as <script src="getimages.php"></script> in the HTML. I'm also getting an error, "galleryPath not defined" in the rotateImages function. I suspect this is because it can't find the PHP script. I'm trying to teach myself web development, so this is a big help for my understanding. Thank you!

Comment: I revised the PHP and HTML to make it more clear what the variables are doing. Also removed the gallery path in the client, instead prepending to the image file name in the returnImages function. It sounds like you have a deeper issue with IIS, you're on your own there.